# Formatting a JavaScript string into 2 columns

Tags: javascript

I am looking to format a string in JavaScript for a "copy and paste" feature. The issue is, it doesn't format based off of dynamic values.

My desired output is something like this.

```
Date of Birth:           11/26/1994
Name:                    Lewis Menelaws
Address:                 123 Apple Road
```

Of course when I am including `\t` in the string, it doesn't come out consistently.

```
Date of Birth:    11/26/1994
Name:    Lewis Menelaws
Address:    123 Apple Road
```

How can I easily format it in the way I want above?

I am currently formatting my strings like such: `'Date of Birth:\t11/26/1994\nName:\tLewis Menelaws\nAddress:\t 123 Apple Road'`

I am using React. I am attempting to have this copied to a clipboard, so I would need a text string.

Comment: Can you post your attempt? A possible way to do this is to iterate over all the rows and find the max width for each column, then pad everything else out per column to match it.

Comment: My mistake, posted above.

Comment: You can manually try to add more tabs in the second and third field: each couple of `key`, `val` adds the same size for the tab, but to achieve your goal you need at least three tabs for `Name` and two for `Address`.

Comment: Please show the code that does this. It's not clear what form your data structures are in to begin with. Is it a 2d array? More details are needed; React seems irrelevant.

Comment: How are you identifying where to put next line `\n` and where to put tab `\t` in the string of dynamic values. Are they pre defined?

Comment: I `map` over an array of "Questions" and answers using template literals.

Answer (score 3):

based on your feedback I have changed my answer...

You could use "padEnd":

```
const content = [
    { columnName: 'Date of Birth:', value: '11/26/1994'},
    { columnName: 'Name:', value:  'Lewis Menelaws'},
    { columnName: 'Address:', value:  '123 Apple Road'},
];

const columnLength = 30;
content.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.columnName.padEnd(columnLength, ' '), item.value)
});
```

So the output will be:

```
Date of Birth:                 11/26/1994
Name:                          Lewis Menelaws
Address:                       123 Apple Road
```

Comment: It's not about styling on a webpage, it's for copying to my clipboard, so I would need a JavaScript string.

Comment: Sorry mate, now I got the message! I've changed my answer... So hope I could help you...

Answer (score -2):

You can use [css grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) or html form elements.